# What is the name of the component that makes progress timeline

Tags: html, css, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I am looking to add to my webpage a component that looks like this:

[image]

Or like this:

[image]

But I have no idea even how to look for it, can anyone tell me what is the name of the component or where can I find something to use it.
I am using primefaces for the most, I haven't found any components like these but I'd rather use one from primefaces if posible

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't add images since my reputation is too low :(

Comment: It would be a good thing for a Primefaces developer to know about the Primefaces showcase imo

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar: What do you mean? If with PrimeFaces developer you actually mean a a developer using PrimeFaces / A PrimeFaces user, then I understand.

Comment: :-) ok, not a native English speaker...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using PrimeFaces, I think you are looking for the "Steps" menu: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/steps.xhtml

Comment: Steps is a better fit I think, ui wise